# When using &:nth-of-type(n), can I then use n as part of an attribute?

Tags: css

For example...

```
&:nth-of-type(n)
  background-image: url(../images/photo**n**.jpg
```

...where the number gets automatically inserted for each one? Or do I need to do it manually, like this:

```
&:nth-of-type(1)
  background-image: url(../images/photo**1**.jpg

&:nth-of-type(2)
  background-image: url(../images/photo**2**.jpg

&:nth-of-type(3)
  background-image: url(../images/photo**3**.jpg
```

Comment: As I know, It's impossible with CSS.

Comment: Yes, you need to add it manually or use a pre-processor to generate them for you.

Comment: http://thesassway.com/intermediate/if-for-each-while

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking is not possible using regular CSS. As you are using `&` in your CSS sample, however, I am assuming you are using a preprocessor like Sass/SCSS or LESS. Given your markup is something like this...

```
<div>
  <span class="for-1">111</span>
  <span class="for-2">222</span>
  <span class="for-3">333</span>
</div>
```

...you can achieve what you're asking using either of these preprocessors:

**SCSS**

```
span {
  @for $i from 1 through 3 {
    &:nth-of-type(#{$i}) {
      background-image: url("../images/photo#{$i}.jpg");
    }
  }
}
```

**Sass**

```
span
  @for $i from 1 through 3
    &:nth-of-type(#{$i})
      background-image: url("../images/photo#{$i}.jpg")
```

**LESS**

```
.setBackgrounds(@n, @i: 1) when (@i =< @n) {
  &:nth-of-type(@{i}) {
      background-image: url("../images/photo@{i}.jpg")
  }
  .setBackgrounds(@n, (@i + 1));
}

span {
    .setBackgrounds(3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, It is not possible. You can use a Pre-processor like SASS of LESS to do this for you. But CSS can't do this.